# Chat Server Mysql error

Tags: c#, mysql, database, raspberry-pi

When i try to start the server i got everytime the same error.
i searched here for a solution and found something that i have to edit my connection string. After this im get the same error again

- Sorry for my bad english

> `RRChatServer.exe
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.EntryPointNotFoundException:
>   CreateSemaphore   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   MySql.Data.Common.Semaphore:CreateSemaphore
>   (MySql.Data.Common.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES&,int,int,string)   at
>   MySql.Data.Common.Semaphore..ctor (Int32 initialCount, Int32
>   maximumCount) [0x00000] in :0   at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check) MySql.Data.Common.Semaphore:.ctor
>   (int,int)   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool..ctor
>   (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionString settings) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPoolManager.GetPool
>   (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionString settings) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open
>   () [0x00000] in :0 [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED
>   EXCEPTION: System.EntryPointNotFoundException: CreateSemaphore   at
>   (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   MySql.Data.Common.Semaphore:CreateSemaphore
>   (MySql.Data.Common.SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES&,int,int,string)   at
>   MySql.Data.Common.Semaphore..ctor (Int32 initialCount, Int32
>   maximumCount) [0x00000] in :0   at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check) MySql.Data.Common.Semaphore:.ctor
>   (int,int)   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool..ctor
>   (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionString settings) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPoolManager.GetPool
>   (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionString settings) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open
>   () [0x00000] in :0`

Comment: You just showed us the exception message. Show your code/work as well.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/W7yFMtMJ this is my mysql class